# Asset with VueJs - Laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

i'am new with **VueJs** , i try to make a new application combine VueJs in **Front side** with Laravel 5.5 **Server side** and i get same problem to define the structure of the project , and how can i acces to assets from .vue files :

**Code component:**

```
<template>
    <div class="row page-titles">
        <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center">
            <h3 class="text-themecolor">Dashboard</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 align-self-center">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**App.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';


axios.interceptors.request.use(function(config){
    config.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken
    return config
})

Vue.prototype.$http  = axios

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

let Mytoolbar = require('./components/Toolbar.vue');
let Mysidebar = require('./components/Sidebar.vue');
let Myfooter = require('./components/Footer.vue');
let Home = require('./components/Home.vue');


const routes = [
  { path: '/home', component: Home }
]


const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes })

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {Mytoolbar,Mysidebar,Myfooter}
});
```

Comment: did you try to see a laravel mix? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix

Comment: Yes i do, i think laravel mix is to combine script or style files together , but my need is  each component has his scipt and style alone : i think is better to use only needed script and style foreach page you know

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the preffered way of doing it. Generally you concat all your JS files and dependencies into 1 or 2 JS files and only load those. If you really need to scope some JS requests to some components, you could maybe load the file on `created()` method in your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices. This script:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should go into either `app.blade.php` at the bottom scripts section.

**OR** (and this is the better way)

You should add it in a vendor directory in `resources/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js`

Then require it in your `app.js` like so:

```
require('./plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js')
```